# Android notification warning log messages

Tags: notificationmanager

System: Android Oreo

I create channel and send notification normal, but i get warning log:

```
W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
W/Notification: See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, solved by moving sound configuration from deprecated Notification.Builder#setSound(...) to the NotificationChannel#setSound(Uri, AudioAttributes)